# Serve flash policy requests on port 80 beside HTTP in node.js

Tags: node.js, flash, http, tcp, crossdomain.xml

I want to serve socket connections from a Flash browser client, and therefore I need to add support for the policy-request-file protocol. I can't run the policy-file-request service on the default port 843 because of firewalls etc. The only option I have is to server the protocol on port 80, beside my HTTP server.

My app is written in node.js and the following code works:

```
var httpServer = http.createServer();

net.createServer(function(socket){
   httpServer.emit('connection', socket);
}).listen(80);
```

I open a socket server on port 80, and for now I just emit the connection event on the httpServer, no problem so far. Now I want to check if the new socket is a policy-file-request which will just send the plain string `<policy-file-request />` over a TCP connection. When I notice this string I know it isn't HTTP and I can return the crossdomain file and close the socket. So what I try now is this:

```
net.createServer(function(socket){
   socket.once('readable', function(){
      var chunk = socket.read(1);

      // chunk[0] === 60 corresponds to the opening bracket '<'
      if(chunk !== null && chunk[0] === 60) {
         socket.end(crossdomain);
      } else {
         socket.unshift(chunk);
         httpServer.emit('connection', socket);
      }
   });
}).listen(80);
```

Now I check if the first byte is the opening bracket '<' and then write the crossdomain file to the socket. Otherwise I unshift the chunk onto the stream and emit the socket as a connection on the HTTP-server. Now the problem is that the HTTP-server doesn't emit a request event anymore and my regular HTTP-requests aren't handled as a result.

I also tried this solution but with no success either:

```
httpServer.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.once('data', function(chunk){
      if(chunk[0] === 60) {
         socket.end(crossdomain);
      }
   })
});
```

When the socket emits the data event, the readyState of the socket is already 'closed' and a clientError event is already thrown by the httpServer. I searched everywhere and didn't found a solution. I also don't want to pipe the data through another socket to another port where my HTTP server is running locally, because that adds to many, unnecessary overhead I think. Is there a clean way to do this in node.js? I tested all this on node.js version 0.10.26.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending crossdomains policy to flash via node js on TLS connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822829/sending-crossdomains-policy-to-flash-via-node-js-on-tls-connection)