# Sending crossdomains policy to flash via node js on TLS connection

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, tls1.2, cross-domain-policy

I have a client which is in flash as3.
I got 2 server, one main for the flash client and a socket policy server.

I run the socket policy server on port 843 and my client on any port X for example.

Now when i connect with my flash client, using this:

```
 Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://domain.com:port");
 SecureSocket.connect(ip, port);
```

It actually connect first to my policy socket server, send a policy-file-request line and receive the one i am sending using my server which look like this:

```
 tls.createServer(options, function(sock) {
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('Data receveid: '.cyan + data + ' from ' + sock.remoteAddress);
            if (data == "<policy-file-request/>\0") {
                    sock.write('<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"><cross-domain-policy><site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/><allow-access-from domain="*"></cross-domain-policy
                    console.log('Sent policy file to: '.green + sock.remoteAddress);
            }
 ...
```

After that, the connection is closed automatically. Then it try to connect to my real server and send to server the policy-file-request line again then connection close. I really dont know what to do from now on ive been trying all days and searching around the web. Anyone got an idea of what i am missing?

Comment: I dont use Javascript sockets but you should check the received contents of `sock.write`. Does it still look correct after writing/sending? Or maybe it was parsed/stripped? Anyways, I would expect it wants byte values not text. Put your text in a crossdomain text file and open that in a hex editor (can use an online one), those bytes shown for the text are what you should send??. Example "hello" is byte values `0x68 0x65 0x6C 0x6C 0x6F` for the letters. Hopefully someone will answer you soon...

Comment: i dont know any way to check this out since flash is sending the cross domain check automatically and receive it in some way i dont control... ill try with wireshark

Comment: I understand Flash does the crossdomain check automatically. I meant just check your text is still formatted like expected whenever you use a `sock.write`. You could check by socket writing into something you control like a JS function or text box in webpage etc. Anyways it auto-closes cause there was a issue. Try **[this answer's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412203/flash-socket-cross-domain-security-issue)** and read this **[Adobe article on Sockets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html)** for hints...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I finally got it to work. First I wanted a SSL connection from my client to my game.

- Trying it locally in the Flash IDE was fine,
- However doing it in flash debugguer or from a website wasn't working
  because it was trying to access a socket policy server (which is a
  registered port from adobe, the port 843).

So I need a policy socket server to work on that port and found some on adobe website wrote in python and perl. Forget them, they won't work in this case.

Because I am trying to access server in SSL so I need also a SSL policy server. 
Since there is none on the net I wrote a simple one:

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/yourserver.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/yourserver.crt'),
};

var HOST = 'YOURSERVERIP';
var PORT = 843;

tls.createServer(options, function(sock) {
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('Policy Server Request: ' + data);
            if (data.indexOf('policy') !== -1) {
                    console.log("Policy Server: sending regulation file");
                    sock.write('<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"><!-- Policy file for xmlsocket://MYDOMAIN.com --><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" /><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="1-65535" /><allow-access-from domain="MYDOMAIN.com" to-ports="MYGAMEPORT" /><allow-access-from domain="MYIP" to-ports="*" /></cross-domain-policy>\0');
            } else {
                    console.log("Policy Server: unknown request");
            }

    });
    sock.on('clientError', function(exception) {
            console.log('' + data);
    });
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
            console.log('CONNECTION CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });
    sock.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('\n' + HOST +':'+ err);
    });
}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('\nPolicy Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

I went crazy in the allow access domain form because i had some security sandbox violation with a reduced one, so ive put it all. I will clean this later.

As you can see, **I had to add a `\0` at end of sending the policy or Flash wouldn't accept it**.

Two day wasted on this. And I still don't understand why Adobe would make the connection so hard between flash and the world. Never saw this kind of policy elsewhere while programming sockets.

Comment: Glad it's sorted and thanks for sharing the useful solution. Yes Flash security can be akward and annoying, its a defence thing. Also when Flash was number 1 for video playback (sometimes via sockets etc) they had to please studios & content makers by showing its difficult to connect & steal data. Now begins the policy file system. Problem is, for a "me" or "you", it becomes akward to access our own content cos of this system.

Comment: How to make encrypted Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://" + host ) request to TLS socket policy server?